Local coefficient system and representation of fundamental group
Let's define a local coefficient system $A\hookrightarrow E \to B$ as a fiber bundle $p\colon E\to B$ where the fiber is a discrete abelian group $A$ and the structure group $G$ is a subset of $\text{Aut}(A)$.
The source I'm reading claims that the monodromy action $\pi_1(B)$ on $E$ is acts by automorphisms of $A$, which follows from the structure group being a subset of $\text{Aut}(A)$. I really can't for the life of my figure out why this is the case. I know that the monodromy action acts as a bijection on the set level, but why must it also preserve the abelian group structure?

That's just the definition of what it means for the structure group to act by elements of $\text{Aut}(A)$. Or are you asking why the monodromy action acts by elements of the structure group?

@QiaochuYuan I guess I would be asking the latter.

Tag "geometry" isn't appropriate : on this site, it is "For questions about geometric shapes, congruences, similarities, transformations, as well as the properties of classes of figures, points, lines, and angles."

Start by defining monodromy of a flat bundle. Then you will see why it lies in the structure group. By the way, the fiber need not have to be an abelian groups or a group at all, it also does not have to be discrete. You need discreteness of the structure group.
